# php compare dates with different years

Tags: php, date, compare

We want to compare two dates, that can be in two different years.

Therefore we tried this, but that does not seems to work

PHP:

```
<?php
    $delivery_date = '08-20-2023';
    $today = '26-07-2022';
    if ($delivery_date > $today){
    echo 'true';
    }else{
    echo 'false';
    }
?>
```

See: https://www.tehplayground.com/sa29CAHd5SuuRkXv

How can we solve this?

EDIT:

Seems that we face another strange thing. For some reason it can not read the date well:

```
$var = '08-20-2023';
$delivery_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var));
```

This will $delivery_date return: `1970-01-01`;

Fetching the following error: `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (08-20-2023) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character`

What are we missing here, because we do not see the unexpected character?

Comment: Hi, you simply misformatted the dates, by default the date has the structure `yyyy-mm-dd`, if you change the date `$delivery_date = '08 -20-2023'` in `$delivery_date = '2023-08-20'` and `$today = '26 -07-2022'` in `$today ='2022-07-26'`, the result of the if statement is true as it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap both of the two date strings in `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. Match the first argument of the function with the format of the date string. You can find reference here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
$delivery_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '08-20-2023');
$today = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '26-07-2022');


if ($delivery_date > $today) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Returns `true`

Comment: The first one appears to be `m-d-Y`

Comment: Good catch, updated

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems that we face another issue, see my edit post.

Comment: @JGeer, your update is using `date` and `strtotime`, please try using the `DateTime::createFromFormat` method as posted. Do _not_ try to get the date back out as a string to perform comparison work, only do that for display or if you need to store it somewhere

Comment: Thanks Chris, sadly we then face the error: `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in`

Comment: @JGeer, you have three distinct problems (that I see so far). The first and second are converting a string to a DateTime followed by comparing those objects. This answer shows you how to do it. The third is how to get that object back to a string, **but not to be used for comparisons**, and that can be done using the [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.

Comment: Thanks Chris, by bad! That's exactly the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

make sure both dates in same format

Proper way

```
<?php
$var = '08-20-2023';
$date_arr=explode('-',$var);
$deliver_timestamp=mktime(0, 0, 0,$date_arr[0],$date_arr[1], $date_arr[2]);
$today = '07-26-2022';
$tdate_arr=explode('-',$today);

$today_timestamp=mktime(0, 0, 0,$tdate_arr[0],$tdate_arr[1], $tdate_arr[2]);

    if ($deliver_timestamp > $today_timestamp){
    echo 'true';
    }else{
    echo 'false';
    }
    
?>
```

simplified

```
<?php
$var = '08-20-2023';
$date_arr=explode('-',$var);
$deliver_timestamp=mktime(0, 0, 0,$date_arr[0],$date_arr[1], $date_arr[2]);


$today_timestamp=time();    
    if ($deliver_timestamp > $today_timestamp){
    echo 'true';
    }else{
    echo 'false';
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems that we face another issue, see my edit post.

Comment: Answer Edited check it make sure dates  are in same format