# how to get month name from month-year (08-2022) string in php

Tags: php, laravel, date-formatting

*how to get month name from month-year (08-2022) string in php*

i want to get this **Aug-2022** (format) from my value **08-2022**

I had tried `date('m-Y',strtotime(08-2022))` and `date('08-2022')->format('m-Y')`

but not working.

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122287/1427345

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert number to month name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a "01-" in front of your value to make it a valid date.

```
$value = "08-2022";
echo date('M-Y',strtotime('01-'.$value));
//Aug-2022
```

try self: https://3v4l.org/ZiB70

or with DateTime:

```
$value = "08-2022";
echo date_create_from_format('!m-Y',$value)->format('M-Y');
```

**Important NOTE:**

That ! in the format is important for this case and is unfortunately missing in many examples for date_create_from_format. If that ! missing then the current day is set as the day. If this happens on the 31st of a month and value is, for example, '06-2022' then a date '31-06-2022' is generated which is then reported as 01-07-2022. With the ! the day is set to 1 and the time to 00:00.

Answer (score 3):

you have to pass date also. so you can try like this way ...

```
$data = "08-2022";
$month = date('M-Y', strtotime('01-' . $data));
```

hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

In This format get **month** name

```
echo date('Y-F-d');
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-M-d');
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use F & M like this

```
echo date("d-M", strtotime('08-2022'));
echo date("d-F", strtotime('08-2022'));
```

for more details
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This code is wrong. https://3v4l.org/asNsg

Comment: i have tried.  not work @SHibon

Answer (score 0):

i have done with it->

```
<?php
    $date = "08-2022"
    $exploreDate = explode('-', $date);
     echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $exploreDate [0], 10)) .' '. '-' .' '. $exploreDate [1];
?>
```

**Answer:** August-2022